# Creatomg specific elements for certain values in data

Tags: node.js, d3.js, powerbi

I am trying to create a table with d3js in node. For the table I'd like to create a column which is sort of a gantt chart. For that I need a svg element in the last column. But I am having difficulties understanding how I can run a function for the last column which use values for other columns and creates a svg element.

Code creating columns and rows:

```
  this.thead.selectAll("th")
  .data(this.HeadColumns)
  .enter()
  .append("th")
  .text(function(d) { return d; });


  let rows = this.tbody.selectAll("tr")
  .data(ViewModel.dataPoints);
  rows.enter().append("tr");
  rows.exit().remove();        


  let cells = rows.selectAll("td")
  .data(function(row) { 
      return d3.map(row).values(); 
  })
  .enter()
  .append("td") //<-- ?
```

At the `let cells` is it possible to run a function on the .append("td") to place a svg element in the last column and run a function on that svg element constructing the visualization?

data looks like this:

```
dataPoints = [
   {
   "Task" : "A",
   "Start": "Thu Dec 01 2011",
   "Finish": Thu Dec 01 2012"
   },
   {
   "Task" : "B",
   "Start": "Thu Dec 01 2012",
   "Finish": Thu Dec 01 2013"
   }
]
```

Full Code:

```
module powerbi.extensibility.visual {

    interface DataPoint {};

    interface ViewModel {
        dataPoints: DataPoint[];
    };

    export class Visual implements IVisual {

        private host: IVisualHost;
        private svg: d3.Selection<SVGAElement>;
        private barGroup: d3.Selection<SVGAElement>;

        private divContainer: d3.Selection<HTMLDivElement>;
        private table: d3.Selection<HTMLTableElement>;
        private tbody: d3.Selection<HTMLTableRowElement>;
        private thead: d3.Selection<HTMLTableHeaderCellElement>;
        private HeadColumns = [];


        constructor(options: VisualConstructorOptions) {
            options.element.style.overflow = 'auto';

            this.host = options.host;

            this.divContainer = d3.select(options.element)
                .append("div")
                .classed("divContainer", true)
                .attr("width", "100%")
                .attr("height", "100%");

            this.table = d3.select(".divContainer")
                .append("table")
                .classed("hello", true)
                .style("background-color", "#72B6E7")
                .attr("width", "100%")
                .attr("height", "100%");

            this.thead = d3.select("table")
                .append("thead");

            this.tbody = d3.select("table")
                .append("tbody");

        }

        public update(options: VisualUpdateOptions) {

            let ViewModel = this.getViewModel(options);
            let width = options.viewport.width;
            let height = options.viewport.height;

            //Creates Header Column Names
            this.thead.selectAll("th")
                .data(this.HeadColumns)
                .enter()
                .append("th")
                .text(function(d) { return d; });

            //Creats Rows   
            let rows = this.tbody.selectAll("tr")
                .data(ViewModel.dataPoints)
            rows.enter().append("tr");
            rows.exit().remove();        

            let cells = rows.selectAll("td")
                .data(function(row) { 
                    return d3.map(row).values(); 
            })
            .enter()
            .append("td")
            .text(function (d) { 
                return d; 
            });
        }

        private getViewModel(options: VisualUpdateOptions): ViewModel {

            let dv = options.dataViews;

            let viewModel: ViewModel = {
                dataPoints: [],
            };

            let Table = dv[0].table
            let TableRows = Table.rows
            let TableLen = Table.rows.length
            let TableColumnNumber = Table.columns.length
            let TableColumns = []

            this.HeadColumns = [];

            for (let i = 0, len = TableColumnNumber; i < len; i++){
                let tmp = {};

                tmp["ColumnName"] = Table.columns[i].displayName;
                this.HeadColumns.push(Table.columns[i].displayName);

                TableColumns.push(tmp);
            }          

            for (let i = 0, len = TableLen; i < len; i++){
                var tmp_ = {};

                for (let k = 0, len = TableColumns.length; k < len; k++){
                    tmp_[TableColumns[k].ColumnName] = <string>TableRows[i][k];  
                }

                viewModel.dataPoints.push(tmp_);
            }
            return viewModel;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: if this is D3 **v4** or **v5** you need to [merge](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_merge) the update and enter selections of your `rows`, i.e. something like `rows = rows.enter().append("tr").merge(rows)`. Otherwise, you'll only be manipulating the updated rows leaving out the newly entered ones.